# JQuery Submit form from success function

Tags: jquery, form-submit

Using the uploadprogress plugin to show the Progress Bar during file upload and try to submit the form from success function. But it doesn't work. Here is the url of the uploadprogress:

http://nixboxdesigns.com/demos/jquery-uploadprogress.php

```
jQuery('#review_form').uploadProgress({ 
  progressURL:'jquery-uploadprogress-demo-simple.php',
  displayFields : ['kb_uploaded','kb_average','est_sec'],
  start: function() { 
   jQuery('#upload-message').html('Uploading files now - please wait.'); 
   jQuery('input[type=submit]',this).val('Uploading... PLEASE WAIT');
  },
  success: function() { 

//$(this).unbind('submit').submit();                            
//$('#review_form').unbind('click');
//$('#review_form').unbind('submit');
// $('#review_form').submit();
// $('#review_form').trigger('submit');
jQuery(this).submit();
  }
```

Comment: Where in the code would you expect the submit to be triggered? I can't see any code which would cause anything to be submitted. And why would you set an "Upload received" message if the form is supposed to be submitted?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to paste the Submission code. I have tested the steps "commented" and none of them work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Progress Bar working is something different of what I expected. The package submitted the form to the location specified in the "form" action attribute. The "file" and other form elements are available there.

I have changed my code to do the actual working there and redirect the page from the calling page. Thus my question to submit the form again is not needed. check one complete example about this:

http://www.ultramegatech.com/blog/2010/10/create-an-upload-progress-bar-with-php-and-jquery/

Thank you for all members who helped me to resolve the issue. And especially "Avi Pinto" for reminding about the necessity of my responses.

Answer (score 0):

Why not `jQuery(this).submit()`?

Answer (score 0):

from your code i see you are trying to submit another form - review_form
Not familiar with this plugin, but looked at his examples and this should work:
$('#review_form').submit();

verify that review_form is a valid form (has an action) with id="review_form"

Comment: Thank you Avi. I have changed that form id and corrected. Actually, it was a mistake when I pasted in the Forum. On my testing page, both form ids are correct. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: I didn't get answers .. But hereafter, I will respond to all answers. For this post, I have replied to all responses. But none of the responses helps me to fix the issue. But it worth.. Is there any way to partially accept the responses?